# Python CSV Data Splitting

Tags: python, csv

I have some data in a CSV file that looks like this:

1. File Owners
2. File1 Bob, Tom, James
3. File2 Tom, Jake, David

I want it to look like this:

1. File Owners
2. File1 Bob
3. File1 Tom
4. File1 James
5. File2 Tom
6. File2 Jake
7. File2 David

Any ideas welcome, I have imported the csv file.

Comment: Could you show us your attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm hoping that your csv file looked like this before:
[Before modifying the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka4hl.png)

```
# I used pandas for this
import pandas as pd
#converting csv file to dataframe
df =pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("dataframe.csv"))

#converts the Files column into a list
files = df['File'].to_list()

#This will be the new dataframe which is a modified version of the first one
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['File', 'Owner'])

for file,row in zip(files,range(len(df.index))):
    # separates the owners from the Owners column, separator is (', ')
    Owners = df.iloc[row,1].split(", ")
    for owner in Owners:
        #Adds the new rows to the dataframe by filename and owner
        new_row ={'File':file,'Owner':owner}
        new_df = new_df.append(new_row,ignore_index=True)

#convert the new dataframe into a csv file
new_df.to_csv('modified_dataframe.csv',index=False)
```

This is what the new csv file looks like:[after modifying the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBF4V.png)